# Sharing utility function that changes component state using this.setState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that is used in a few places that conditionally heals the component data if it was not bootstrapped with this data.

```
getMissingData() {
    axios.get(endpointWithMissingData(), { withCredentials: true })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          this.setState({ dataNeeded: res.data.data, loading: false })
        } else if (this.state.tryCount >= 3) {
            this.setState({ loading: false, isError: true })
        } else {
          this.setState((prevState) => {
            return { tryCount: prevState.tryCount + 1 }
          })
          setTimeout(this.getMissingData.bind(this), 5000)
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        this.setState({ loading: false, isError: true })
      })
    }
```

What is the most "React" way to be sharing this function across multiple components? I plan on putting it in a utility file and exporting it to these different components.

They are not under the same parent component or area of the application, so it doesn't make sense to bubble this data down from the parent; we are also trying to defer this call if we can but still need to handle this case.

Comment: Try to make it into a pure function that transforms a promise into an Promise containing an object that the component that uses it can just do `this.setState(promiseResult)`

Comment: The thing is, this "retry" functionality is pretty important to the specific API call (the calculation takes a while on the server) and that previous state . tryCount + 1 is integral to that calculation. I like the idea of calling this utility function and using setState on the .then of the promise it returns with the state data I need to change.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about a retry functionality in the question.
But if you do need one, you can still make it configurable with a parameter. (like retryTimes with default 0)